# Help with back-end choices for a mobile application

Tags: java, android, web-services, servlets, push

As a part of our CS grad project, we are developing an android application that receives push recommendations from our server based on geolocation logic & social-networking APIs.
We still have lots to learn & following are the choices we have made:

1. Poll for recommendations as normal HTTP requests
2. Push the data in XML formatting
3. Serve using Java Servlets in Tomcat
4. Keep the application logic separate from the servicing layer for adding other kinds of client access later. Maybe by calling separate Java classes from the Servlet Classes.
5. MySQL
6. Our java code shall also interact with the Facebook API to start with and some Map APIs
   (All this sounds scary as of now!)

Could you please comment/differ on our choices? We would love to give back to the community as we learn ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. push the data in JSON
2. I would choose PHP over Java on server side, as Facebook and Map APIs have a lot of examples in PHP compared to other languages. Keep these APIs on the server as much as you can, as you will be able to change the server faster than a mobile application which has a submission process.
3. target newest SDK versions with more powerful pushing technologies ([c2dm](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html) over http polling)
4. If you have heavy computing task on the mobile device, choose to program them in [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) maybe it comes handy to do it in c++ compared to java